# react redux api middleware is not working

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am using Redux API Middleware to call the api for the data

Action.js

```
import { CALL_API } from 'redux-api-middleware';

export const FETCH_POSTS = 'FETCH_POSTS';
export const FETCH_POSTS_SUCCESS = 'FETCH_POSTS_SUCCESS';
export const FETCH_POSTS_FAILURE = 'FETCH_POSTS_FAILURE';

export const fetchPosts = () => ({
  [CALL_API]: {
     types: [

  {
        type: FETCH_POSTS,
        payload: (action, state) => ({ action: state })
      },
      {
        type: FETCH_POSTS_SUCCESS,
        payload: (action, state, response) => {
          return response
        }
      },
      FETCH_POSTS_FAILURE

     ],
    endpoint: 'http://localhost:8080/v1/career/',
    method: 'GET',
  }
});
```

Reducer.js

```
import {
  FETCH_POSTS,
  FETCH_POSTS_SUCCESS,
  FETCH_POSTS_FAILURE
} from '../actions/Action';

import {combineReducers} from 'redux'

const INITIAL_STATE = { postsList: { posts: [], error: null, loading: false } };

export const posts=(state = INITIAL_STATE, action)=> {
  let error;
  switch(action.type) {

  case FETCH_POSTS:
    return { ...state, postsList: { posts: [], error: null, loading: true} };
  case FETCH_POSTS_SUCCESS:
    return { ...state, postsList: { posts: action.payload, error: null, loading: false } };
  case FETCH_POSTS_FAILURE:
    error = action.payload.data || { message: action.payload.message };
    return { ...state, postsList: { posts: [], error: error, loading: false } };

  default:
    return state;
  }
export const reducers=combineReducers({

    posts:posts
    });
export default reducers;
```

Store.js

```
import {
  applyMiddleware,
  createStore,compose
} from 'redux';

import { apiMiddleware } from 'redux-api-middleware';
import reducers from './reducer'


export function ConfigureStore(IntitialState={}){
    const stores=createStore(reducers,IntitialState,compose(
        applyMiddleware(apiMiddleware),
         window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f
        ));
    return stores;
}; 
 export const  store=ConfigureStore()
```

I can see only the FETCH POSTS is running and when i check the state i get this

[image]

I checked the network section of the developer tools.The response is coming from the server
[image]

and my response is [image]

I dont know why this not working.Please some one help me .Thanks.

Comment: In `post ` reducers console `action`.Check if the data is coming properly

Comment: you are correct.The problem is that the api server havent implemented the cors.So there was a No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in the response.So the browser rejected the response.Now after adding it its working.Thanks @ RIYAJ KHAN.Saved my day!!!!!